# Ask alarmManager not to display alarm time and icon on screen and on top

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to invoke some receiver exactly on time, hence i am using alarm clock to set this using the following code. Everything works except on my screen and on top of the screen i see alarm icon and time. Similar to what u see when u set alarm using alarm clock app in android. I dont want to see this. How can i go about it?

```
private static void updateNextAlarmInAlarmManager(Context context, long nextAlarmTime) {
        // Sets a surrogate alarm with alarm manager that provides the AlarmClockInfo for the
        // alarm that is going to fire next. The operation is constructed such that it is ignored
        // by AlarmStateManager.

        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        final int flags = 0;
        final PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 /* requestCode */,
                createIndicatorIntent(context), flags);

        final AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(nextAlarmTime, getPendingIntentForApp(context, nextAlarmTime));
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(info, operation);
    }
```

Before moving `setAlarmClock`,  i was using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`, but `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` doesnot guarantee that it willl deliver event exactly on time. But it doesnot show the alarm icon on screen, which is what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i go about it?

Don't use `setAlarmClock()`. As [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) states, "the system will typically also use the information supplied here to tell the user about this upcoming alarm if appropriate".

Comment: But there is no other option, as setExactAndAllowWhileIdle is not reliable. Do u know of any other approach?

Comment: @user93796: Not really. For the past few years, I have been recommending that developers not try to create apps that rely on background work, particularly ones for which timing is important.